# More months in a year than days in a week

Tags: grammar, prepositions, conjunctions, prepositional-phrases

Is it right to say,

> There are **more months in a year than days in a week.**

My question is how to compare between two groups of words using *'than'*?

Comment: Yes, perfectly correct – five more, in fact.

Comment: Cardinalities are comparable when there exists an injective function from one set to the other. Here is one: Monday->January, Tuesday->February, Wednesday->March, Thursday->April, Friday->May, Saturday->June, Sunday->July.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this sentence sounds right to me. You've also constructed it correctly!

According to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/than), "than" is used to express the second member/second part of an unequal comparison.

In your sentence, I infer that there are **12** months in a year and **7** days in a week. Both numbers are not equal, so you're evidently on the right track!